# Загрузка системы дополнительным программным потоком.

Tags: windows, многопоточность

Здравствуйте!
Все знают, что рутину можно вынести в отдельный поток и выполнять там, не загружая при этом основной. Так вот, а если рутины так много, что приходится создавать третий и четвертый потоки? Приложение разгрузится, а вот как же сама система Windows? Будет ли она загружена сильнее, если потоков в программе более двух? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вопрос сложный, сильно зависит от того, что делается в этих потоках, версии операционной системы и архитектуры процессора. Если потоки дают сильную нагрузку на процессор, то нецелесообразно стартовать потоков больше, чем количество ядер процессора,так как выигрыша в скорости не будет никакого.

Собственно, выполнение рутины в отдельном потоке делается, в первую очередь, для того, что интерфейс приложения не "подвисал". Увеличение числа фоновых потоков осмысленно, только если задача хорошо разделяется на параллельные потоки выполнения. Такое разделение - это, обычно, нетривиальная задача.

Comment: Ну то, что если потоков больше, чем ядер процессора, то это смысла не дает, понятно. Спасибо.